# Find version number of certain plugins in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

More specifically I need to write code so that I can find the Eclipse Version number (4.7.0). I can't look it up in a file (.eclipseproduct or about.mappings) and I need to make an API call.

So I was wondering whether I'll be able to find out the version number of the plugin `org.eclipse.platform` by some Java program.

Comment: Why can you not read it from .eclipseproduct? Are you within Eclipse as plugin or are you attaching to a running instance?

Comment: Is this code going to be in an Eclipse plugin or is it a separate Java program?

Comment: Hi greg-449 Lets suppose a separate Java program and not a plugin.
PerDigre Reading it from .eclipseproduct is not going to be the most effective solution for me once I have the eclipse version.

Comment: You may have to describe your problem better. Is the Eclipse you want to read the version from in a different process? Is this from a Unit test? or is this from RCPTT or another GUI tester?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is to get it from the system properties, assuming you're within Eclipse as runtime-workbench.

```
System.getProperty("eclipse.buildId")
```

If you're not within the Eclipse context then there's either the installation files like ".eclipseproduct" or through the debugger.

Comment: Sop(System.getProperty("eclipse.buildId")) returns null for me.

Comment: It's being set in Eclipse context, ie runtime-workbench. For me it reads "4.7.0.I20170612-0950".

Comment: In your eclipe.ini file do you have a eclipse.buildId=4.7.4.7.0.I20170612-0950 ?

Comment: No that's only within the running Eclipse instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the bundle (the representation of a plug-in in the OSGi runtime) for a given symbolic name with `Platform::getBundle`. Once you have a bundle, you can query its version. For example:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle( "org.eclipse.ui.ide" );
System.out.println( bundle.getVersion() );
```

getBundle asks the OSGi runtime to search all installed bundles for a bundle with the given symbolic name.

Comment: Does this work only on plugins if that bundle is available in my manifest file?

Comment: No, it is sufficient if The bundle in question is available at runtime. E.g. it may be a transient dependency of your plug-in.

Comment: Right now I'm executing a separate Java program, so not a part of a plugin. RIght now Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.platform") returns null to me. The same with any "org.*" bundle that I enter.

Comment: This approach does only work from within the same VM. It wasn't clear to me that the version query rund in a different process. Maybe you would want to clarify your question.